# Reading state values from a ILogger Scope

Tags: asp.net-core, ilogger

Is there a way to read/grab 'current scope' values?  For example, I've added some 'global context' values in an IPageFilter:

```
// OnPageHandlerExecuting
var contextScopeValues = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "UserId", "user-id-value" }
};
contextScope = logger.BeginScope( contextScopeValues );

// OnPageHandlerExecuted
contextScope?.Dispose();
```

If I call `logger.LogInformation( "Doing something for {UserId}" );` during any of the page processing, this works and the message is rendered with proper `UserId`.

However, when using `LoggerMessage`, it throws a parse error if you don't have a string parameter.

```
public static class LoggerMessages
{
    private static readonly Action<ILogger> sampleActivity;

    static LoggerMessages()
    {
        // This line throw exception because a parameter was 'expected'
        sampleActivity = LoggerMessage.Define( "Start some activity for {UserId}" );
    }

    public static void SampleActivity( this ILogger logger ) => sampleActivity( logger, null );
}
```

Implemented correctly, it would look like this and pass in a string.

```
public static class LoggerMessages
{
    private static readonly Action<ILogger, string> sampleActivity;

    static LoggerMessages()
    {
        sampleActivity = LoggerMessage.Define<string>( "Start some activity for {UserId}" );
    }

    public static void SampleActivity( this ILogger logger, string userId ) => sampleActivity( logger, userId, null );
}
```

However, if I pass in a dummy value, it replaces the 'core context' value for all logging calls going forward.  So I was hoping to be able to do something like `logger.SampleActivity( logger.Scope[ "UserId" ] );` but it obviously does not exist.  Do I have any options to use `LoggerMessage` for performance and use the 'core' UserId property?

Comment: Hi @Terry,you can see this [thread](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-include-scopes-when-logging-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/) may helpful.

Comment: Thanks.  I've actually read that already and that seemed more geared towards scopes lost due to exceptions, but doesn't talk about how to grab a scope property value that might have already been set.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Terry looks like we use a so-called `IExternalScopeProvider` to get the scoped values (although not in a dictionary style). The scoped values are designed for ***custom logging provider*** to consume. Each provider has a private `IExternalScopeProvider` injected and you cannot access it from outside, unless you write your own custom provider like this https://www.meziantou.net/asp-net-core-json-logger.htm So there will not be an easy way for you to get and log out the scoped values using the built-in and third-party logging providers.